# AFNetWorking POST request timeout if response data size is too long

Tags: post, timeout, size, afnetworking

timeout error always return back, if response data size is too long,(eg: data size > 5M),  how can i right it from error,  i try to set time out value to 3min, but the same error returned, can you help me , thanks very much.

Comment: Can you include sample code?

Comment: that's ok now, i set timeout value with 20min, because the net speed is slowly very much